# Why do i get this error when i connect snowflake and python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

This is  the error i get when i connect to snowflake via python?

```
OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)
```

I connect using:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(

          user='JoeBloggs',
          password='pwd',
          account='JoeBloggs',

          database='DEV_DATA'

         )
```

do i need to feed in other paramters such as port, host, etc how did i find what these are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your value for 'account' needs to be modified.  It looks like you're using your username there, but it should be the Snowflake account.  This should be the portion of the URL that you connect directly to that precedes the snowflakecomputing.com portion.  For example, 'xy12345.east-us-2.azure'.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts are that the error indicates a firewall or proxy issue. In particular, a proxy might intercept Snowflake's SSL certificate and replace it with their own. The best way to resolve this is to ensure the certificate is trusted in the proxy and the proxy is configured as per Snowflake's documentation so that the Snowflake certificate can pass through.

The documentation below has more information on using a proxy with SnowSQL. You can pass along the error with issuer details to your network engineer and can request to whitelist the required URLs (documentation also below outlining the whitelisting requirements). You can use the SYSTEM$WHITELIST function to get all the URLs to whitelist in a proxy or firewall for your account.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-a-proxy-server
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/hostname-whitelist.html

Answer (score 0):

```
First, install Snowflake python connector .pip3 install snowflake-python-connector.

Can you try with code below:

------------------------------------------------------

import snowflake.connector

PASSWORD = '*****'
USER = '<UNAME>'
ACCOUNT = '<ACCNTNAME>'
WAREHOUSE = '<WHNAME>'
DATABASE = '<DBNAME>'
SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'

print("Connecting...")
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
  user=USER,
  password=PASSWORD,
  account=ACCOUNT,
  warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
  database=DATABASE,
  schema=SCHEMA
)

con.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE " + WAREHOUSE)
con.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE " + DATABASE)

try:
    result = con.cursor().execute("Select * from <TABLENAME>")
    result_list = result.fetchall()
    print(result_list)

finally:
    con.cursor().close()
con.cursor().close()

---------------------------------------------------
```